# 2 lines of script take half minutes to execute?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-controls, customization

I have a function:

```
function reNameThisSheet() {
    var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    active.setName(active.getRange('A2').getValue());
}
```

which I trigger manually by pressing run button in script editor and it takes more than half a minute (32 - 33 seconds) to execute it = to get the desired name on desired sheet.

I run this function after I duplicate the last sheet in spreadsheet and before runing this function I run one other function which sets the value in A2 according to the sheet index.

Function that sets value to A2 according to the sheet Index of active sheet is a native formula:

```
=indirect("Category!B" & (ReturnSheetIndex()-1))
```

which includes custom formula ReturnSheetIndex():

```
function ReturnSheetIndex() {
  var sheetIndex  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getIndex();
  Logger.log(sheetIndex);
  return sheetIndex;
}
```

This function I trigger manually so that I point on it in script manager and click save and thus value in A2 is set instantly.

After value in A2 is set instantly it takes ages that function reNameThisSheet() renames the sheet created by duplication of last sheet.

All this is happening in spreadheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/151TbRey12wGrbdfcGI14U50b5dNcJaHCX2UKRVv6teA/edit?usp=sharing

Aditional testing gave followig results:

When I close the spreadsheet down and open it again it even does not even load properly sheets that were created by duplication process :(

It hangs up...

The titel of the sheets which are created with formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(indirect("Category!C" & (1+findCell())),"  od  ", TEXT(MIN(E5:E),"dd.mm.yyyy") ,"  do  ", TEXT(MAX(E5:E),"dd.mm.yyyy") ," :")
```

does not even appear :(

Error: Loading Data ... apears in first row of each sheet and stays so :(

I think there is the problem with function:

```
function findCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Category");
  var sheet1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var student = sheet1.getRange("A2").getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == student) {
        row = values[i][j+1];
        return i;
      }
    }    
  }  
}
```

Which is incorporated in creating the title in row 1 of sheets created with duplication.

But funny: if I try to duplicate last sheet after reopening the spreadsheet, everything works ok.

Only the sheets that were created before closing and reopening have problem with not loading function findCell().

Any idea why so will be very much appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: I created a copy and it runs very fast for me, maybe try the same

Comment: Something went wrong. Please reload.
There wasan error during calculation; some formulas may not calculate successfully. Undo your last change and try again. Dismiss.
Unable to load file
Try to load it again or send an error report

Comment: This error came up when I made a copy as you suggested and I tried to duplicate last sheet. But after reloading copied spreadheet everything looks ok... I don't understand  Any explanation would be very much appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: Did you try to close down the copied spread sheet that you made and open it again? Do this and go through the sheets and you'll see that the sheets are not as they should be... titels are wrong and result of formula in A5 =sort(filter... is also wrong... All because of function findCell() which does not recalculate properly ???

Comment: How large is the spreadsheet? If it has a lot of sheets and formulas then it might be why it seems to take long

Answer (score 1):

Have solved my problem by creating a custom menu option "Custom -> Duplicate and Name" that copies a predesigned template sheet to the end of all sheets and names it from the list of names in "Category" sheet according to the index of the sheet created at the same time with only two clicks of mouse

It took me one week of googling and research and bothering here to get this together

```
function duplicateName() {
  var menu = [{name: "Duplicate and Name", functionName: "dupName"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}

function dupName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var totalSheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  var lastSheet = ss.getSheets()[totalSheets-1];
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(lastSheet);
  var templateSheet =  ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  var getNameFromSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Category");  
//  var name = Browser.inputBox('Enter new sheet name');
  var getNameFromRow =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getIndex()-1;
  var name = getNameFromSheet.getRange(getNameFromRow, 2).getValue();
  var dateCell = getNameFromSheet.getRange(getNameFromRow, 2); 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    if (dateCell.isBlank()) {                         
     var result = ui.alert(
     'Vse Kategorije so že odprte',
     'Ni več možno ustvariti nove kartice!',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  } else {
      ss.insertSheet(name, {template: templateSheet});
  }
}
```

It works as a charm on:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kte7OU0WB-u8fDhASWDLQzLJaf7dSRvxUgRfY5pIObg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Answers and Questions on this site should be wrote as technical documentation, so please don't include emoticons, salutation, greetings, thanks, ... Reference:
- [What should I keep out of my posts and titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/289691)

Comment: You can give me a minus wote as you usually do :)

Comment: If you can't help at least try not to do harm by giving negative votes. This is my humble request to you with all due respect. My sincere and best regard to you. Thank you Sir.

Comment: I didn't vote yet on this Q&A :) You should not feel offended when your posts get down-votes, instead you should think if you could improve them.